# Next JS Custom Server app.render do not pass query to a component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to pass `userData` with `app.render`, but while **Server side rendering** `router.query` is empty, although i have passed `userData`! Is it NextJS's bug, or am i doing something wrong?

app.js:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {

    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/index') {
      app.render(req, res, '/index', {
        userData: {
          id: 1,
          name: 'admin'
        }
      })
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(3333, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
```

pages/index.js:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { query } = router;

    return (
        <div>
            Query: {JSON.stringify(query)}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: What's the output when you just print `query` without stringify-ing it?

Comment: contai@Leander it's also empty. but there are two messages in console log. as i think the first (empty) is sent by the server, and the other (contains id) is sent by the browser. i don't know why the first is empty, if i pass some data with app.render

Comment: why you dont use getInitialprops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If getInitialProps is absent, Next.js will statically optimize your
>   page automatically by prerendering it to static HTML. During
>   prerendering, the router's query object will be empty since we do not
>   have query information to provide during this phase. Any query values
>   will be populated client side after hydration.

You can access your query using  `getInitialProps`.
with `useRouter`:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const Index = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { query } = router;

  return (
      <div>
          Query: {JSON.stringify(query)}
      </div>
  );
};

Index.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {};
};
export default Index
```

with a class component:

```
import React from 'react'

class Index extends React.Component {
      static async getInitialProps (context) {
        let query  = context.query;
        return {query}
      }

      render() {
        let {query} = this.props
        return (
          <div>
              Query: {JSON.stringify(query)}
          </div>
      );
      }
    }
export default Index
```

Or if you prefer a  functional component :

```
const Index = (props) => (
  <div>
    Query: {JSON.stringify(props.query)}
  </div>
)

Index.getInitialProps = async ( context ) => {
  let query  = context.query;
  return {query}
}

export default Index
```

Please note that obviously this works with `/index` but not with `/`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's as simple as adding a return statement before `app.render` to prevent the rest of the code from executing.

```
if (pathname === '/index') {
  return app.render(req, res, '/index', {
    userData: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'admin'
    }
  })
} else {
  handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
}
```